# Issues converting from dtype ('O') to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm importing a large number of text files and appending them to a pandas dataframe. There's a column with a bunch of dates I need, but I can't convert them to datetime because it's listed as an object. This line of code works for other any other dtype, but it throws an error when I run it here.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%d%y')
```

After running, it returns this error:

```
time data '01/07/2014' does not match format '%m%d%y' (match)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try add `/` twice and change `y` to `Y`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

See more [info](http://strftime.org/) about formatting `datetime` in `python`.

Comment: There we go; should be good now. Sorry; sometimes it errors out and won't accept it.