# How can I check Index type in Python Data Frame?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timedelta

There is my Data Frame, it has more than `45,000+` values.

[image]

Basically I work on `bar_chart_race` graph but suddenly it throws an error.

> `ValueError: Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill) or backfill (bfill). Got linear`

then I found a solution on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843656/pandas-interpolation-valueerrorinvalid-fill-method-expecting-pad-ffill-or). But there is an another issue how can i check Index data type? because in given link it can find issue with datetime format then it can be solved. but how can i know about type of index? e.g. `Datetime` , `Date` , `timedelta`,`Object` or a `string`?

About Data frame those value directly come from an `API` .
Any other solutions?
`Bar_Chart_race` datetime as an index.

Comment: Use `df.index.dtype`

Comment: it can return `dtype('O')`. what does it mean?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562101/15981783 for an explanation of this dtype.

Comment: Then you can see this for converting the index to datetime https://stackoverflow.com/a/36264850/15981783. But instead use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, ...)`

Comment: Can it work directly on Index or can i convert from columns then i can do that just like in a given link?

Comment: Use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: It can show an error `TypeError: <class 'tuple'> is not convertible to datetime`

Comment: Try doing `df.index = df.index.map(lambda x : str(x[0]))` first to cast the first element of the tuple to a string.

Comment: It can remove date Index.

Comment: Without the DataFrame this is a hard problem to debug. Print out the contents of the index, see why it's a tuple & what the elements of the tuple are. The goal is to convert the date part of the tuple to a single string as the index, then use the `pd.to_datetime` function on it.